# Enabling Gridster resize AFTER grid has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, gridster

I'm wanting to give users the option to make all the grids in their Gridster dashboard resizable (after the grid has been rendered), but I cannot seem to get it to work. I've tried both these options after the user has made a choice, but they do nothing:

```
gridster.resize = {
    enabled: true
}

gridster.resizable({
    resize: {
        enabled: true
    }
})
```

I wondered if there was then a way of reloading the Gridster widgets without the user noticing, but couldn't find anything that would do this without reloading the entire page.

BTW I tested resizing does work in the first place by enabling it at the start like so:

```
// dashboard_config is a JSON file containing all the dashboard settings
gridster = $(dashboard_config.target).find("ul").gridster( {
    widget_base_dimensions: dashboard_config.widget_base_dimensions,
    widget_margins: dashboard_config.widget_margins,
    max_size_x: 10,
    max_size_y: 5,
    draggable: { 
        handle: 'h2'
    },
    resize: {
        enabled: true
    }
} ).data('gridster');
```

Incidentally I am also giving users the option to toggle 'dragging' after the grid has been loaded. This DOES work by doing one of these after the user has made a choice:

```
// turn on dragging
gridster.enable()

// turn off dragging
gridster.disable()
```

If anyone has any ideas, that would be great.

Thanks!

*UPDATE*

I've come across enable_resize() & disable_resize(), but I get this error in my Firebug console (and subsequently it doesn't work):

```
TypeError: this.resize_api is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Sorry if I'm being annoying answering my own question, I really did look for ages before initially posting!

enable_resize() & disable_resize() are indeed the correct functions to use to toggle resizing AFTER the grid has been initialised.

It seems the user below found the same bug, but worked around it by enabling resizing in the initialisation, but immediately disabling resizing afterwards. This is to do with the resize_api not being created at the start if resizing set to false. I can only think this is a bug...

https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/issues/316

Answer (score 0):

You can create a deep copy of the gridster configuration and assign null to prev config and assign it again to re trigger the gridster reload.